# How did these characters survive in The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, star-wars-finn

In the final battle on Crait, the Resistance tries to destroy the First Order's big fancy battering ram. Finn and Rose end up  crashing right in front of this weapon and the entire first order army. All other resistance craft were either destroyed or had retreated on Poe's orders. Soon after this, Finn is shown dragging an unconscious Rose back inside the resistance base.

How did Finn manage to drag Rose back inside the resistance base when he had to drag her the entire way back while all that time being very clearly visible to the First Order army (who also had the order to not give any quarter or take prisoners)? How did Rose and Finn survive that? How did they make it back into the Resistance base alive?

Comment: Finn found Frodo's elven cloak

Comment: Portable plot shield emitters.

Comment: Finn punched a hyperspatial plot hole through the space-time continuum and dragged Rose back at FTL (Faster Than Logic) speed.

Comment: The writers were on Finn's side

Comment: Finn was not wearing a red shirt, and so benefitted from plot armor...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Per the [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition), Finn *dragged* Rose back through the breached door. The walkers ignored him and the ground troops hadn't disembarked yet.

> *Working quickly, **Finn rigged a makeshift travois out of broken hull plating and wiring and strapped Rose to it.** He didn’t have time to process what she’d said to him, before she kissed him, or to worry about how badly she might be hurt. He had to focus on getting her to a safe place. Fortunately, he remembered his survival training—or, more accurately, he’d drilled enough that it had become muscle memory, with his hands knowing what to do even while his brain stumbled and fumbled.*
>
> *It occurred to him that, ironically, he had Phasma to thank for that.
> There was a long crack in the door to the old rebel base now. **Finn double-checked that Rose wouldn’t fall off the contraption he’d rigged, tilted the travois, and began to pull it behind him, hurrying across the salt plains toward the distant lines of the trenches.
>
> He kept glancing at the towering walkers, fearing that at any moment one of the huge, animal-like heads would tilt their way and open fire. But the walkers simply trudged along without taking any apparent notice of them.**
> After a moment he realized why.
>
> They don’t think we matter. Because they know they’ve won.*

The film's [junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_A_Junior_Novel) suggests that smoke and rough ground may have also (partially) shielded them from view.

> *Finn stripped wire from his skimmer. The smoke had drifted past, so he
> could inhale without worry. But his lips tingled strangely, probably
> from the salt in the air. Or was it from Rose’s kiss? She lay on a
> metal sheet he’d torn off the skimmer. He corded the wire around her
> waist and her legs so she wouldn’t slip off. The leftover wire he used
> to rope the skimmer’s laser barrels through the holes he’d punched
> into the sides of the sheeting. He then lifted both barrel ends and
> started to pull Rose on his improvised sled.*
>
> *The going was tough, the ground slippery. **Finn had to take a longer
> route back to the mine, to avoid the thickest patches of smoke.
> Whenever they were out in the open, Finn dreaded the seemingly
> inevitable laser barrage. Yet for some reason, the gorilla walkers
> ignored them.***

Comment: It is very plausible that the First Order were simply going to take care of cleanup when the ground troops disembarked.  Two people, one of whom is badly injured, was no threat at that time.  Survivors would be dealt with in the fullness of time.

Comment: Shows a remarkable level of discipline, come to think of it.  But then, with a very few exceptions, discipline was never one of the First Order's weaknesses.

Comment: I can't clearly remember, but I think this could not be what happened in the movie.  There should have been a long, obvious trail of disturbed, red sand/salt/whatever in subsequent shots from the dragged travois.  I don't think there was such a thing.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy  -We jump-cut to him pulling her into the trench. Time has clearly passed

Comment: @zibadawatimmy There may also have been a cross-wind blowing the white salt coating back over any trails made.  For example, nearing the end of this show down, I also don't recall seeing the many trails that should have been left by the groundspeeders when they were going out in the first place.

Comment: Novelization (predictably) never explains why Finn seems to be faster dragging ample Rose on foot then riding alone on speeder. :)

Comment: @rs.29 - Through the magic of continuity editing